# blocked In-Bound Registration for ejabberd-18.12.1-2 because Spam

Tags: debian-stretch, ejabberd

On my debian stretch vps I have a xmpp server ejabberd-18.12.1-2 ~ bpo9 + 1. The anti spam precautions I took are:

> registration_timeout: 2600

A captcha to protect IBR (in-bound registration) which I thought was a nuisance necessary for users who register with the server, but still necessary in order to stop spam robots.
It too proved to be useless.

> captcha_host: "my.ejabberd.xmpp: 5280"
>   captcha_cmd: "/usr/share/ejabberd/captcha.sh"

A regex that forces users to register using a username format, a single point or a minus sign or a possible underscore and a two-digit number at the end and no more, this to try to somehow prevent the formation of names hexadecimal with random characters but this was also useless.

> ```
> user_regexp:
>    - "^ [a-zA-Z] + (?: [_ -]? [a-z0-9]) * $"
> ```

An ACL to stop bogons out of address ips:

> bogons:
>       ip:
>         - "0.0.0.0/8"
>         - "10.0.0.0/8" ....

a long black list of IPs and domain names of xmpp servers known to spread spam with another set of fake account addresses collected through the analysis of logs and via the ejabberd web administration panel.

> spamhosts:
>       server:

These are the precautions I have taken and I was not able to stop the waves of fake account creations for the propagation of spam via IM.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Maybe it's time to disable In-Band Registration, and use mod_register_web. Or even better, write your own registration page (with whatever CAPTCHA system you find strong enough), that calls "ejabberdctl register".

Comment: I wanted to avoid but that's what I did. fake accounts have exceeded a thousand and only in the last two hours 400 fake accounts have been created. IBR is an important and convenient function for those who want to approach the use of an IM client for instant messaging, and it is a function that I wanted to keep at all costs but every precaution has been in vain.
Now it is possible to register only via the web.

Comment: a good patch could be to use a script similar to the one that generates the captcha but instead generates a clickable link that leads to a web registration page.